# how to launch a share post option in linkedin from flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a social media app for that i need to share a post from my flutter app to a linkedin post  and facebook(like a promotion)

I have tried plugin like (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me)
version:flutter_share_me: ^1.4.0

I need to know how to integrate linkedin's share a post option in flutter app

Comment: You tried that, what's the issue with it?

Comment: You could try Share Plus: https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

Answer (score 1):

> One way of doing this using **[share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus)** package.

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:file_selector/file_selector.dart'
    hide XFile; // hides to test if share_plus exports XFile
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart'
    hide XFile; // hides to test if share_plus exports XFile
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

import 'image_previews.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const DemoApp());
}

class DemoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DemoAppState createState() => DemoAppState();
}

class DemoAppState extends State<DemoApp> {
  String text = '';
  String subject = '';
  List<String> imageNames = [];
  List<String> imagePaths = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Share Plus Plugin Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0x9f4376f8),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Share Plus Plugin Demo'),
          elevation: 4,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Share text',
                  hintText: 'Enter some text and/or link to share',
                ),
                maxLines: null,
                onChanged: (String value) => setState(() {
                  text = value;
                }),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Share subject',
                  hintText: 'Enter subject to share (optional)',
                ),
                maxLines: null,
                onChanged: (String value) => setState(() {
                  subject = value;
                }),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              ImagePreviews(imagePaths, onDelete: _onDeleteImage),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                label: const Text('Add image'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Using `package:image_picker` to get image from gallery.
                  if (!kIsWeb &&
                      (Platform.isMacOS ||
                          Platform.isLinux ||
                          Platform.isWindows)) {
                    // Using `package:file_selector` on windows, macos & Linux, since `package:image_picker` is not supported.
                    const XTypeGroup typeGroup = XTypeGroup(
                      label: 'images',
                      extensions: <String>['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
                    );
                    final file = await openFile(
                        acceptedTypeGroups: <XTypeGroup>[typeGroup]);
                    if (file != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        imagePaths.add(file.path);
                        imageNames.add(file.name);
                      });
                    }
                  } else {
                    final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
                    final pickedFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(
                      source: ImageSource.gallery,
                    );
                    if (pickedFile != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        imagePaths.add(pickedFile.path);
                        imageNames.add(pickedFile.name);
                      });
                    }
                  }
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 32),
              Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    ),
                    onPressed: text.isEmpty && imagePaths.isEmpty
                        ? null
                        : () => _onShare(context),
                    child: const Text('Share'),
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    ),
                    onPressed: text.isEmpty && imagePaths.isEmpty
                        ? null
                        : () => _onShareWithResult(context),
                    child: const Text('Share With Result'),
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _onShareXFileFromAssets(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Share XFile from Assets'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onDeleteImage(int position) {
    setState(() {
      imagePaths.removeAt(position);
      imageNames.removeAt(position);
    });
  }

  void _onShare(BuildContext context) async {
    // A builder is used to retrieve the context immediately
    // surrounding the ElevatedButton.
    //
    // The context's `findRenderObject` returns the first
    // RenderObject in its descendent tree when it's not
    // a RenderObjectWidget. The ElevatedButton's RenderObject
    // has its position and size after it's built.
    final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;

    if (imagePaths.isNotEmpty) {
      final files = <XFile>[];
      for (var i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
        files.add(XFile(imagePaths[i], name: imageNames[i]));
      }
      await Share.shareXFiles(files,
          text: text,
          subject: subject,
          sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
    } else {
      await Share.share(text,
          subject: subject,
          sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
    }
  }

  void _onShareWithResult(BuildContext context) async {
    final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    final scaffoldMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
    ShareResult shareResult;
    if (imagePaths.isNotEmpty) {
      final files = <XFile>[];
      for (var i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
        files.add(XFile(imagePaths[i], name: imageNames[i]));
      }
      shareResult = await Share.shareXFiles(files,
          text: text,
          subject: subject,
          sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
    } else {
      shareResult = await Share.shareWithResult(text,
          subject: subject,
          sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
    }
    scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(getResultSnackBar(shareResult));
  }

  void _onShareXFileFromAssets(BuildContext context) async {
    final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    final scaffoldMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
    final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/flutter_logo.png');
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    final shareResult = await Share.shareXFiles(
      [
        XFile.fromData(
          buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes),
          name: 'flutter_logo.png',
          mimeType: 'image/png',
        ),
      ],
      sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
    );

    scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(getResultSnackBar(shareResult));
  }

  SnackBar getResultSnackBar(ShareResult result) {
    return SnackBar(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text("Share result: ${result.status}"),
          if (result.status == ShareResultStatus.success)
            Text("Shared to: ${result.raw}")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```